# Why am I getting a 'called object 0 is not a function error'?

Tags: c

I'm a C# developer trying to learn C (followed by C++). I am going native, working on Ubuntu using vim as my text editor, and the Gnu C Compiler (gcc) to compile.

I'm trying to write a simple Celcius => Fahrenheit converter and I am getting the following error:

> called object '0' is not a function

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i+20)
    {
        int celcius = (5/9)(i-32);
        printf("%d - %d \n", i, celcius);
    }
}
```

I am compiling with this:

```
gcc FahrenheitToCelcius.c -std=c99
```

Could somebody point what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious, does (4)(5) mean (4)*(5) in C# ?

Comment: @CharlieBurns I'd like to know that too, but seems to be true.

Comment: Actually no it doesn't, I don't know why I thought it did! Thanks guys, also I can't upvote until I get 15 points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C (and I am assuming that in other languages too :)) an arithmetic operator is needed to perform an arithmetic operation.
Change

```
int celcius = (5/9)(i-32);
```

to

```
int celcius = (5/9)*(i-32);
```

Answer (score 6):

As people have pointed out

```
int celcius = (5/9)(i-32);
```

Should be

```
int celcius = (5/9)*(i-32);
```

However the reason you are getting that particular error message is that

```
int celcius = (5/9)(i-32);
```

is being evaluated at run time as

```
int celcius = (0)(i-32);
```

And the runtime system sees (0) as a pointer.

So you need to change your math to avoid the integer division

Answer (score 3):

This line is problematic:

```
int celcius = (5/9)(i-32);
```

because the compiler thinks you're trying to invoke a function specified by `(5/9)`. If you wished to do a multiplication, you should do:

```
int celcius = (5/9)*(i-32);
```

instead.

Moreover, if you expect floating-point values to be returned from that calculation, you should do:

```
int celcius = (5.0/9.0)*(i-32.0);
```

because `5/9` is an integer division and will never return a floating-point value.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
int celcius = (5/9)(i-32)
```

to

```
 int celcius = (5/9)*(i-32);
```